# Deploying Kubernetes cluster on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, coreos, kubernetes

I'm currently trying to go through this tutorial: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/coreos_multinode_cluster.html

As far as I know, I have AWSCLI set up and configured properly, and EC2 tools as well.  I have gone through the first set of instructions:

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name    kubernetes --description "Kubernetes Security Group"
{
    "GroupId": "sg-3876e341"
}

C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name kubernetes --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0

C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name kubernetes --protocol tcp --port 80 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0

C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name kubernetes --source-security-group-name kubernetes
```

But I hit issues when I try to deploy:

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-e9aec689 --key-name kuberneteskeys --region us-west-1 --security-groups kubernetes --instance-type t2.micro --user-data file://master.yaml

A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the RunInstances operation: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
```

I'm not really sure where to go with that error -- my searches haven't been too fruitful and as far as I know I'm using the command properly.

Any insight to this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the security group GroupId instead of the name for the value of --security-groups and you should find it will work. This will be necessary because a VPC is being used.

As an aside, I'd highly recommend you look at Terraform. There are a few scripts out there to turn up a Kubernetes cluster on AWS - with a single command.

Comment: Ok, I gave that a go and got the following:

C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-e9aec689 --key-name kuberneteskeys --region us-west-1 --security-group-id sg-3876e341 --instance-type t2.micro --user-data file://master.yaml

A client error (InvalidGroup.NotFound) occurred when calling the RunInstances operation: The security group 'sg-3876e341' does not exist in VPC 'vpc-678c1c02'

Sorry if these questions are really basic!

Comment: Never mind, was just a region issue!  Thanks for the help!